# SQL select from single SQL table where a value exists in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, pivot, sql-server-2019

I have this table:

| Fruit | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Abbey |
| Bananna | Abbey |
| kiwi | Charley |
| Apple | Bobby |
| grapes | Luke |
| orange | Beth |
| Apple | Eric |
| Mango | Charles |
| Pear | Dave |
| Bananna | Eric |

This is sample data. The actual table has nearly a million rows.

I need to pull rows with names based on two data items. For example, I want to know who bought both `banana` and `apple` in one output, like so:

| Fruit | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Abbey |
| Bananna | Abbey |
| Apple | Eric |
| Bananna | Eric |

I tried this:

```
Select Fruit, name
From table
Where x = apple and x = banana
```

But it doesn't run. How can I do this?

Comment: *"But it doesn't run"* What does "doesn't  run" mean? Do you get an error? What is that error?

Comment: You want to show Abbey and Eric, because they both bought Bananna and Apple. But you don't want to show there names only, but the complete rows with the fruits they bought. Yes? What if one of them also bought Mango, would you want to show this row, too, or still just the Bananna and Apple rows?

Comment: Can there be duplicate entries, e.g. two rows for Abbey and Apple?

Comment: If you only wanted to show the final list of `name` then it's much easier `select name from YourTable where name in ('Apple', 'Banana') group by name having count(*) = 2` assuming no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions, which in most cases are more efficient than self-joins or multiple subqueries.

If there are no duplicate fruit/name tuples, then:

```
select name, fruit
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by name) cnt
    from mytable t
    where fruit in ('Apple', 'Banana')
) t
where cnt = 2
order by name, fruit
```

Else:

```
select name, fruit
from (
    select t.*,
        max(case when fruit = 'Apple'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by name) has_apple,
        max(case when fruit = 'Banana' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by name) has_banana
    from mytable t
    where fruit in ('Apple', 'Banana')
) t
where has_apple= 1 and has_banana = 1
order by name, fruit
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response, First option = 25252 rows, Looking good, this has hte best results of the suggestions - however returns some rows where users have bought 2 x apples, but no bananas.

the second response with the "case when" returned no results

Comment: @user125942: *however returns some rows where users have bought 2 x apples, but no bananas*. So that means you have duplicate fruit/name tuples, which makes the first query inadequate (I mentionned it in my answer). You can use the second query instead. Here is a fiddle where one can see that it works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/jEi8feUN

Comment: yes that latter one nailed it. Many thanks for that. (and introducing this fiddler, never knew such thing existed)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE Fruit IN ('Apple', 'Banana')
    GROUP BY [Name]
    HAVING COUNT(Fruit) >= 2
)
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks, i treid this answer. IT gave me some 533987 rows,however is only gave users who had apples then listed all their other fruits also. no mention of bananas ??

Answer (score 1):

Just another option  EXISTS

```
Select * 
 from  YourTable A 
 Where exists (Select 1 from YourTable where Fruit = 'Apple'  and [Name]=A.[Name])
   and exists (Select 1 from YourTable where Fruit = 'Banana' and [Name]=A.[Name])
   and Fruit in ('Apple','Banana')
```

Comment: I couldn't find an issue with this answer! maybe a performance issue in comparison with other answers? but it is still a valid answer.

Comment: Hi, many thanks, i treid this answer. IT gave me some 95884 rows, users did have apple and banana but it also returned all the other fruit they bouight also. Im thinkinng this could work if i select into a new table then just select outht eapples and bananas to further filter

Comment: @user125942 Just add to the WHERE   ...  and Fruit in ('Apple','Banana')  See update

Answer (score 0):

you can add list fruit in cte

then filter table2 with cte and find count per fruit

must count per fruit equal count list

```
;with _list as (
    select 'Bananna' as fruitname
    union all 
    select 'Apple' as fruitname
)
select 
         fruit
       , Name
from ( 
        select 
                  fruit
                 ,Name
                 ,count(*) over(partition by  name order by (select 0)) as c
        from table2 
        where fruit in (select fruitname from _list)
)a
where a.c=(select count(*) from _list)
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
create table table2( fruit varchar(100),    Name varchar(100))

insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Apple',  'Abbey')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Bananna',    'Abbey')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('kiwi',   'Charley')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Apple',  'Bobby')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('grapes', 'Luke')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('orange', 'Beth')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Apple',  'Eric')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Mango',  'Charles')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Pear',   'Dave')
insert into table2(fruit,Name) values('Bananna',    'Eric')
```